# Golang count number of fields in a struct of structs

Tags: go, struct

Given a struct `CompleteStruct` that is composed of two embedded structs `StructA` and `StructB` where `StructB` has `ImbStructC` in it.

```golang
type StructA struct {
    AA int
    AB int
    AC int
}
type ImbStructC struct {
    BCC int
}
type StructB struct {
    BA int
    BB int
    ImbStructC
}

type CompleteStruct struct {
    StructA
    StructB
}
```

How do you extract the total number of fields in the inner struct?

```golang
reflect.TypeOf(CompleteStruct{}).NumField())
```

returns 2, I assume because `CompleteStruct` is made up of 2 embedded structs.

What code can I use to show that `CompleteStruct` has 6 fields?

Comment: Recursion is needed here - as you have to take into account the embedded structs may themselves have embedded structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is needed to solve this, as an embedded struct field may itself embed another struct.

Also, one should be careful not to count embedded structs as field - these are listed as "anonymous" fields in the `reflect` package:

```
func countFields(v any) int {
    return rvCountFields(reflect.ValueOf(v))
}

func rvCountFields(rv reflect.Value) (count int) {

    if rv.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return
    }

    fs := rv.NumField()
    count += fs

    for i := 0; i < fs; i++ {
        f := rv.Field(i)
        if rv.Type().Field(i).Anonymous {
            count-- // don't count embedded structs (listed as anonymous fields) as a field
        }

        // recurse each field to see if that field is also an embedded struct
        count += rvCountFields(f)
    }

    return
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/IjOllo86_xk

Output:

```
main.CompleteStruct : count = 5
main.StructA        : count = 3
main.StructB        : count = 2
main.StructC        : count = 6
main.StructD        : count = 12
main.Empty          : count = 0
int                 : count = 0
```

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right track, is recrusion really needed though? See my answer below.

Comment: Depends on your use case, but it's not usual for structs to be nested many levels deep. If you know the structs won't be nested, then you don't need recursion. But if they are nested at arbitrary depths, then recursion is the way to go.

Comment: the `reflect.VisibleFields` package flattens out the nested structure. Or is there a reason not to use that package?

Comment: Again depends on your use case:.`VisibleFields` may work, but will only expose the "visible" exported i.e. capitalized struct field names. It will not include lowercase (unexported) struct fields. So if you only want exported fields, then this would work, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The `reflect.VisibleFields` package lists all the fields in the struct, from there is "just" a matter of counting those fields that are not Anonymous.

```
func CountNumberOfFieldsInAStruct(obj interface{}) int {
    fields := reflect.VisibleFields(reflect.TypeOf(obj))
    count := 0
    for _, field := range fields {
        if !field.Anonymous {
            count += 1
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

As @colm.anseo mentions "this will only expose the "visible" exported i.e. capitalized struct field names. It will not include lowercase (unexported) struct fields. So if you only want exported fields, then this would work"

Tested here

https://go.dev/play/p/Ea-y8YAkcqZ

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get the number of fields from the parent struct and then loop through the children and get the number of fields for each child and then add them up

```
innerFields := 0

numOfFields := reflect.TypeOf(CompleteStruct{}).NumField()

for i := 0; i < numOfFields; i++ {
    innerFields += reflect.TypeOf(CompleteStruct{}).Field(i).Type.NumField()
}
```

This code is tested and works

Comment: This does not account for an inner field, itself embedding another struct.